# String Pattern Matching Algorithm Used in Different Applications

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, file, data-structures

I want to know which algorithm is used by the following **Applications or WebSite** for  **String Pattern Matching**, I have already search by title but nothing found, i want to learn and understand the real time implementation of String Pattern Matching algorithm used by various Applications.

**1.Notepad**
**2.Adobe Reader**
**3.Web Browsers**
**4.URL locator**
**5.StackOverFlow WebSite**

Thanks in advance......

Comment: The [help/on-topic] clearly states that questions asking us to find or recommend off-site resources are off-topic here. Please take a few minutes to review those guidelines. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, i did'nt get you?

Comment: *Please give me resources or references* is not an acceptable question here. See the link I provided to find out why. I don't know what is unclear about *your question is off-topic*. :-)

Comment: sorry, now i have changed it,please tell me know how to learn about them?

Comment: Your question is still too broad. You're asking people to investigate different software and web sites and then explain what they're doing. This presumes that all of them make their algorithms public, and it's highly unlikely that any one answer can explain all of them.

Comment: Actually i have given them as an example, you can tell me anyone of them, and also i found that StackOverFlow website is uses FINITE Automata. this type of answer i want, i don't want all algo implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance a single string matching is the z-algorithm. It's the fastest matcher.

Comment: please also tell me the area where they are mostly implemented.. and thanks.......

Comment: @vishgupta92:Can you please send me an e-mail? Thank you!

Comment: mine id is vishgupta92@gmail.com